# How to execute SQL queries and put results into a result table without loading data into app memory?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, ibatis

I have a number of tables with a large amount of data into my Oracle 11g database.

Data is continuously arriving at the tables and every 15 minutes I have to process unhandled data.

What I should do basically is to execute SQL queries, primarily complicated joins, against the tables, merge the data and send it to Elasticsearch.

The data is supposed to be too big to be accommodated within application memory thus my suggestion is to execute the queries on a low level, put the results to a dedicated result table and after do pagination and send it to Elasticsearch.

I can predict a bottleneck on the processing stage.

Can `Hibernate` or `iBatis` execute SQL queries and put the results into a result table on behalf of a database without loading the data into application memory?

Comment: You can perform plain SQL queries with hibernate. As long as you don't return anything from the query, hibernate can't load it into application memory